# Every time I instantiate new object, attribute goes back to zero

Tags: java, object, constructor, runtime-error, member

I am building a class `Rating` as following:

```
public class Rating{
//class attributes
private Movie movie;
private PremiumUser premiumUser;
private double rating;
private int id;

private int count;
protected static Rating [] ratings = new Rating [100];

public Rating(Movie movie, PremiumUser premiumUser, double rating){
    this.movie = movie;
    this.premiumUser = premiumUser;
    this.rating = rating;
    ratings[count] = this;
    count += 1;
    this.id = count;

}
public void setRating(int rating){
    this.rating = rating;
}

public void setMovie(Movie movie){
    this.movie=movie;
}

public void setPremiumUser(PremiumUser premiumUser){
    this.premiumUser = premiumUser;
}

public int getID(){
    return id;
}

public PremiumUser getPremiumUser(){
    return premiumUser;
}

public Movie getMovie(){
    return movie;
}

public double getRating(){
    return rating;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return ("Rating ID: " +id + "\nMovie: "  + movie.getTitle() + "\nPremium User: " + premiumUser.getUsername() + "\nRating: " + rating);
}
}
```

But every time I create a new object `Rating` (like so):

```
 Rating rating1 = new Rating(movie1,marios, 9.0);
    Rating rating2 = new Rating(movie2,zarko, 8.5);
    Rating rating3 = new Rating(movie1, jdoe, 10);
    System.out.println(Rating.ratings[0] + "" + Rating.ratings[1]);
```

What I get from the `System.out.println` line is only the last `Rating` object I created. I am not sure why that happens. Debugging print statements in the constructor suggest that count goes back to zero every time I create a new object.

Answer (score 3):

Change your variable declaration to `private static int count;`

**Explanation**

According to your logic, your `count` variable appeals to all instances of the class therefore it should be `static`. If you don't put static, it will be initialized for each object of the class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

`count` is an instance member, and every time you instantiate a new object, it gets its own `count`, initialized to `int`'s default, `0`. It should be a `static` member, shared between all the `Rating`s objects:

```
public class Rating {
    private static int count; //here
    protected static Rating [] ratings = new Rating [100];

    // instance variables, constructor, methods, etc
```

Answer (score 2):

> First you want to know about `static` keyword:
>
> - Attributes and methods(member of a class) can be defined as `static`.
> - `static` members do not belongs to an individual object.
> - `static` members are common to all the instances(objects of the same class).
> - `static` members are stores in static memory(a common memory location which can by everybody).

The `static` modifier indicates that the `rating[]` array is common to all the `Rating` in the whole class rather than to an individual object.

But the `count` variable is not. so each and every time when you create object `count` variable value become `0`. Because it is individual for every object.

To avoid that(solution):

add `static` modifier to count variable. It should be like below:

```
private static int count;
```